# How do I write a killer proposal on Upwork as a newbie?

Tags: freelance-websites, difficult-client, project-management, fixed-price, budget

I am a freelancer by profession. I have worked for a long time in the field. Recently I have shifted to Upwork. As the platform is very good for freelancers, more and more people are joining here. I also want to be a part of this platform. But while creating my profile, I am stuck in some sections. Also, I want to clear my mind about a few things. Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.
Is freelancing on Upwork worth my time?
How do I write a killer proposal on Upwork as a newbie?
What should be done to get a project as a freelancer on Upwork?
Which is the best online earning website, Freelancer, Fiverr, or Upwork?
How do freelancers get paid on Upwork?
What is your best experience with freelancers on Upwork?
Where can I find coupons for Upwork? I have found some coupon sites on Google. I have mentioned them below. Share your thoughts about them?

Comment: "the platform is very good for freelancers", "is freelancing on Upwork worth my time ?", "Which is the best ?": mh, isn't this contradictory ? And what is the connection to the title ?

Comment: The question, "is freelancing on upwork worth my time?" is not a question we can answer. That can only be answered by experimenting and see what the results are.

Answer (score 0):

Proposals on Upwork or for prospects that you have found on your own are very similar. They need to address the real issues that the prospect sees. Note: I state the issues that the prospect sees. You may see issues that they don't, but they won't hire to fix those issues.

Proposals can be short or long. That all depends on the size of the prospect and the size of the project. Proposals can include timelines, proposed project management strategies, payment stages, examples of how you have solved problems in the past, portfolio samples, etc. These all depend on what the project is supposed to solve.

Whether or not a proposal is a "killer" all depends on the prospect. They are the ones to decide, not us. Try to make a proposal to fit what you believe the prospect wants to see.

You have no control over what other proposals the prospect receives. As a "newbie", you are at a disadvantage. Many people try to "buy into a market" by coming in with low cost. That works when there isn't a lot of competition. Under high competition, that only depresses the pay level for everyone.